# Delete cookie only works in headfull but not in headless - puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

I successfully can delete cookies in headfull mode by using:

```js
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCookies');
await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCache');  
console.log( 'done..' );
```

As far as I understand the code above is using the dev tools to archive this. In headless instead this code is not working. Just nothing happens and the code stucks and the console.log will not come. I assume that in headless mode the dev tools is not started?

Is there a way to use the code from above in headless mode?

I currently do as workaround Incognito page each new url. However I would like to have a more clean solution like the code above.

Greets

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use incognito mode and close the page then re-open a new page with a fresh cookie

```
(async () => {
  var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  var browser = puppeteer.launch();
  var context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
  var page = await context.newPage();
})();
```